# Python: Maximize and Return screen location of an application using PID

Tags: python, python-3.x, pid, maximize

I am new to python so bare with. I want to pass a process ID (PID) to python and then maximize the window and then return the location that screen is at so if i have 2 monitors (or `n` many monitors) it will be maximized and then return the location so I can click certain buttons on that.

Should be scale able but I will be using it on excel, I have an add in which esquires a log in and password but cannot be automated through VBA.

This way I can take where the application currently is, offset the key sequence and click.

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: Windows - with Pycharm